# Drupal website with Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-7, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a Drupal site template however I have an issue, this is my current docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    restart: always

  site:
    image: drupal
    container_name: site
    ports:
      - "555:80"
    volumes:
        - ./drupal:/var/www/html
    links:
      - database:database
    working_dir: /app
    restart: always

volumes:
  db:
```

Now if I do that the site doesn't work, no files are in the /var/www/html directory and the site 404's on everything. However if I remove the volume in the site container, it works perfectly and I can start setting it up as if it was a regular site.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use an absolute path instead of ./drupal? Are you running docker-compose in the same directory where your compose file lives?

Comment: By the way, looks like you've declared a volume you're not using (db).

Comment: Hi Brian, yeh seems to be the case, if I run docker-compose config it will fill in those relative paths with absolute paths.

Comment: And good point about the db volume, I'll scrap that one, and just to clarify yes I'm running docker-compose from the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't map a volume in the `site` service, that means Drupal is using whatever's already in `/var/www/html` from the `drupal` image. When you map the volume, you're overwriting `/var/www/html` with whatever's in `./drupal` on the host machine. The results you're seeing imply there may be something wrong with the contents of `./drupal`. To start with, I would run the service without mapping a volume and then copy the exact contents of `/var/www/html` into your local folder:

```
docker cp compose_site_1:/var/www/html/ ./drupal
```

Then try running the service again, this time with the volume mapped and see if that works. If it works, that tells you the problem was with the contents of `./drupal`.

Comment: Hi, that does appear to be the case, how would I mount the the /var/www/html/ so that I could edit the files etc? Create a volume then link the two directories?

Comment: Use docker cp to copy the files from /var/www/html/ inside the container to the ./drupal directory on your machine. Next, without editing the files, run the container again, this time using the volume mapping in your original post, and verify that the container still works. Then start editing the files in ./drupal according to your needs.